# Text field white when it should be transparent in CSS?

Tags: css

I have seen multiple answers however I have not managed to solve my problem with them so far.

I have a some text fields that are like this:

```
.form-wrapper .field-list .field .field-element{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,255);
}
```

So here, it will get the existing boxes (text fields) and it changes the background to a semi-transparent black and also change the text color to white. However when I click in the text field it goes from being the semi-transparent black to a plain white color. Any help on how to fix/make it the same color as the text field background? - Thanks

***NOTE***

I have seen some stuff like this:

```
#inputId:-webkit-autofill {
background-color: white !important;
}
```

But this has not worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:focus` pseudo element.

```
.form-wrapper .field-list .field .field-element:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

You could even style the focused form and the non-focused form at the same time:

```
.form-wrapper .field-list .field .field-element,
.form-wrapper .field-list .field .field-element:focus,
{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,255);
}
```

I would suggest that you create some kind of style difference for the focused input form. This is for accessibility/usability reasons.

Comment: That has not worked I am afraid. Instead, it has inverted it. So the text fields are white and when you click on them they go black? Is it something to do with my `background-color`?

Comment: Ahhhh! The new stuff has worked! Thank you so much. I used the edit that you put in and it has worked fine! Thanks so much :)